# OpenID: unauthenticated POST becomes GET after authentication

Tags: openid

I'm trying out OpenID Connect for my app and there is one specific workflow that I haven't been able to support.

I've got an "Add to cart" button that issues a `POST` request to the HTTP server. If the user is not authenticated, the user goes to the Identity Provider to be authenticated. However, after the user is authenticated, the Identity Provider redirects the browser to the `redirect_uri` using a `GET`, which means my application loses the context of which item the user wanted to buy.

The only alternative that I can think about would be to hide the "Add to cart" button until the user logs in, but it seems like this would be an important limitation of OpenID. Is there another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the user is not authenticated, the user goes to the Identity Provider to be authenticated.

This is the first redirect with which you lose the POST information.

So when deciding that the user has to be redirected, you need to store the POST data in the session and pick them up after the user has been logged in.

Comment: Yes, the thought of storing the POST information in a Cookie occurred to me after I posted the question. I haven't tested it yet, but I can't see why it wouldn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A redirect is always going to become a GET request, there is no way to preserve the body of POST in case of redirection. So you have few things you could do

1. Show login instead of Add to Cart
2. The login redirect URI should have a get request to a special add to cart URL with enough information. So basically an additional GET endpoint instead of just POST for adding product to cart
3. Allow cart to be managed without being authenticated, this what most ecommerce solution would do